# Maya MFnPlugin::registerUI to call Python instead of MEL scripts

Tags: c++, python, maya, mel

I have a C++ Maya plugin. When loaded, it automatically calls MEL procedures to create the GUI:

```
  status = plugin.registerUI("LoadGUI", "UnloadGUI");CHECK_STATUS(status);
```

However, registerUI seems to be available for MEL procedures only.

**How could I do similar things for Python?**

Comment: Couldn't you call the python yourself manually in a event.

Comment: @joojaa: thanks for your answer. Well, I thought that because Autodesk thought about a nice way to do that with MEL, there could be a nice way to do that in Python. Or what is the "best" way to have a plugin load a python GUI into maya when it is loaded?

Comment: That's because the original idea was that **all Maya GUI** is to be built in MEL. We live in transitional times where we need to accept the loss of optimal solutions because all MEL can not magically be ported to python instantaneously. Best is not defined.

Comment: @joojaa: like design patterns, I am however pretty sure that for such a common thing, there is a "normal" way to do that. If it is to call python scripts from an Event, then why not.

Comment: Because Autodesk is more concerned in making new features for marketing to hype, than keep the API tidy. The priority of the API just is lower. This isn't the only oversight. Seems to me that this is Autodesks basic approach on design. Buy with money then let bitrot set in. Remember this is not Alias|Wavefront anymore.

Comment: @joojaa: I didn't know it was that bad. Do you believe it is thus best to stick with MEL instead of Python then?

Comment: @Korchkidu - 4 years later, the situation is just as ugly. Nevertheless, Python is so superior to MEL as a language, that it is worth the pain - IF you are doing complex scripts. And the pain is high: the documentation is not clear; some tasks can only be done by calling MEL from Python, and most docs are C++ APIs; the so-called Python documentation does not make it clear how to actually call this stuff. Whenever I want to do something, I search until I find some Python script that is somewhat similar, to see what they do. (Even though I programmed in both C++ and Python before using Maya.)

Comment: Equally bad, there is a mish-mash of approaches:  When to use "Python API 1" vs "Python API 2"?  How does PyMel fit into this?  No easy answer. Hence it comes down to finding existing examples, and working from there. BUT for a beginner, I'd say spend your first YEAR in MEL - Python in Maya is so screwed up, that it is only worth it once you are doing a lot of heavy-duty scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the mel command call your python command.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This seems pretty ugly. I would like to remove all MEL stuff and convert everything to Python. I am sure that Autodesk thought about a nice way to create a Python GUI when a plugin is loaded.

Comment: Well, the the way Autodesk has chosen to transition to python makes Maya really ugly on so many levels. In fact they actually have broken many of Mayas best features as they have gone along in this direction. Autodesk is not just doing this job properly. They botched the entire process day one.

Comment: Ok I see. I didn't know it was that bad.